# Как инициировать вызов метода destroy() интерфейса DisposableBean

Tags: java, spring

В контексте изучения `Spring` столкнулся с методами `afterPropertiesSet()` и `destroy()` интерфейсов `InitializingBean`, `DisposableBean` соответственно. Имплементировал в своем Классе два этих интерфейса и реализовал в нем оба вышеуказанных метода.

При создании бина, метод инициализации `afterPropertiesSet()` - успешно отрабатывает. Подскажите, как инициировать вызов метода `destroy()` интерфейса `DisposableBean`? Не могу разобраться.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true"
>

```
<bean id="t1000" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.robot.ModelT1000" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg value="silver" index="0" type="String"/>
    <constructor-arg value="2006" index="1" type="int"/>
    <constructor-arg value="true" index="2" type="boolean"/>
    <property name="hand" ref="toshibaHand" />
    <property name="leg" ref="toshibaLeg"/>
    <property name="head" ref="toshibaHead"/>
</bean>

<bean id="t1000Empty" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.robot.ModelT1000">
    <constructor-arg ref="sonyHand"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="sonyLeg"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="toshibaHead"/>
</bean>

<bean id="t1000P" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.robot.ModelT1000">
    <constructor-arg value="silver" index="0" type="String"/>
    <constructor-arg value="2006" index="1" type="int"/>
    <constructor-arg value="true" index="2" type="boolean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sonyHand" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.sony.SonyHand" />
<bean id="sonyHead" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.sony.SonyHead"/>
<bean id="sonyLeg" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.sony.SonyLeg"/>

<bean id="toshibaHand" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.toshiba.ToshibaHand" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="toshibaHead" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.toshiba.ToshibaHead" />
<bean id="toshibaLeg" class="ru.javabegin.training.spring.impls.toshiba.ToshibaLeg" />
```

Ниже привожу методы afterPropertiesSet() и destroy() в бине, который имплементирует инт-сы InitializingBean и DisposableBean:

```
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(this + " method Destroy()");

}

public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(this + " method Init()");
}
```

Comment: `destroy()` же в конце выполнения вызывается. а если надо в середине выполнения программы, то может просто ее вызвать как метод?

Comment: В том то и дело, что он определен, но не вызывается по завершении программы. Я переопределил эти два метода - вставил в них печать текста в консоль - метод afterPropertiesSet() инициирует печать своего текста, а destroy() - нет. Я так понял, он должен также автоматически вызываться по завершении работы программы, как автоматически вызывается метод afterPropertiesSet() при инициализации бина.

Comment: пришли spring.cfg.xml и метод destroy()

Comment: Сюда, прямо в коммент кинуть текст из файла и метод?

Comment: нет. дополни вопрос

Comment: Дополнил, но в spring.cfg.xml вы ничего не увидите, т.к. запуск этих методов инициируется на уровне класса - реализацией интерфейсов InitializingBean, DisposableBean. И, как я уже говорил, afterPropertiesSet() работает, а destroy() - нет.

Comment: попробуйте добавить `@PreDestroy` перед `destroy()` методом и скажите результат

Comment: а как вы завершаете программу?

Comment: @Senior Automator не работает

Comment: @Vartlok программа отрабатывает операции, вызванные в main() и завершает работу: "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: в описание бина добавьте `init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy" `

Comment: @Vartlok спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался - нужно, по заверении программы, принудительно закрывать Spring контекст посредством метода close() - context.close(). Только в этом случае вызывается метод destroy(). Но для этого нужно, при создании контекста, задавать тип переменной context не посредством общего интерфейса ApplicationContext, а использовать конкретную реализацию этого интерфейса ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context или ConfigurableApplicationContext context, например. Только в конкретных реализациях этого интерфейса может быть вызван метод close().